# Array in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I had simple key in the **totalwithouttax** with 3000, **totaltax** with 10 and **totalamtincltax** with 2000 in my interface.
And I had echo the array, the **totaltax** and **totalamtincltax** echo the right value that I key in, But **totalwithouttax** echo 1000 only and data inserted in database is 1.000000.

Please help me. Thank You.

Controller:

```
    $custTd = $post['id'];
    $custMame = $post['name'];
    $custEmail = $post['email'];
    $custAddr = $post['address'];;
    $custTel = $post['telno'];
    $remarks = $post['remark'];
    $paymentOption = $post['options'];
    $promoCode = $post['promo_code'];

    $arraySize = count($post['totalwithouttax']);
    for($i=0; $i<$arraySize; $i++){

    $totalWithoutTax = $post['totalwithouttax'][$i]; //$post['totalwithouttax'];
    $totalTax = $post['totaltax'][$i]; //$post['totaltax'];
    $totalAmtInclTax = $post['totalamtincltax'][$i];//$post['totalamtincltax'];

    //MASSAGE DATA TO BE INSERTED TO ARRAY
    $orderHeader = array(
                                    'user_id' =>  $custTd,
                                    'status' =>  1,
                                    'cust_name' =>  $custMame,
                                    'cust_email' =>  $custEmail,
                                    'cust_addr' =>  $custAddr,
                                    'cust_tel' =>  $custTel,
                                    'remarks' =>  $remarks,
                                    'pay_option' =>  $paymentOption,

                                    'total_without_tax' =>  $totalWithoutTax,
                                    'total_tax' =>  $totalTax,                              'total_amt_incl_tax' =>  $totalAmtInclTax,
                                    'epp_first_payment' =>  $eppFirstPayment,

                                  );

    //INSERT ORDER HEADER
    $orderHeaderId = $this->order->InsertOrderHeader($orderHeader);
```

view:

```
<tr class="item-details">
                        <td><span class="rowNumber">1</span></td>
                         <td class="">
                        <?php
                        $options = array(
                                         '' => '~Choose An Item~'
                                         );
                        foreach ($item as $rows){
                            $options[$rows->id] = $rows->item_name;
                        }

                        $select = array(

                                        'id' => 'item_id',
                                        'class' => 'form-control'
                                        );
                        echo form_dropdown('item_id[]', $options,set_value('item_name'),$select);
                        ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class=""><input type="number" class="item-qty" name="qty[]" min="0.00" /></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="weight[]" class="weight" step="any" /></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="transportation[]" class="transporation" step="any" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="gp[]" name="gp[]" value="" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="discount[]" name="discount[]" value=""/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="unit_price[]" name="unit_price[]" value="" /></td>
                        <td align="right">
            <input type="text" id="totalwithouttax" name="totalwithouttax[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td align="right">
            <input type="text" id="totaltax" name="totaltax[]" value="">
            </td>
            <td align="right">
            <input type="text" id="totalamtincltax" name="totalamtincltax[]" value="">
            </td>
                     </tr><br/>
```

Comment: What data type you used on saving the **totalwithouttax** in your database? Is there any equations performed before it saved?

Comment: @Roshan an error **Uninitialized string offset: 0** in line **$totalWithoutTax = $post['totalwithouttax'][$i];**

Comment: This error would occur if any of the following variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays.

Comment: Way to go bro!!

Comment: are you getting single input with this name `totalwithouttax`?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong way calling post method

```
    $custTd = $_POST['id'];
    $custMame = $_POST['name'];
    $custEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $custAddr = $_POST['address'];;
    $custTel = $_POST['telno'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remark'];
    $paymentOption = $_POST['options'];
    $promoCode = $_POST['promo_code'];

    $arraySize = count($post['totalwithouttax']);
 for($i=0; $i<=$arraySize; $i++){

$totalWithoutTax = $_POST['totalwithouttax'][$i];
$totalTax = $_POST['totaltax'][$i]; //$post['totaltax'];
$totalAmtInclTax = $_POST['totalamtincltax'][$i];

//MASSAGE DATA TO BE INSERTED TO ARRAY
$orderHeader = array(

                            'user_id' =>  $custTd,
                            'status' =>  1,
                            'cust_name' =>  $custMame,
                            'cust_email' =>  $custEmail,
                            'cust_addr' =>  $custAddr,
                            'cust_tel' =>  $custTel,
                            'remarks' =>  $remarks,
                            'pay_option' =>  $paymentOption,

                            'total_without_tax' =>  $totalWithoutTax,
                            'total_tax' =>  $totalTax,                              
                             'total_amt_incl_tax' =>  $totalAmtInclTax,
                            'epp_first_payment' =>  $eppFirstPayment,

                          );
```

}

Comment: I had **$post = $this->input->post();** above the **$custTd = $post['id'];**